# how do you add up the output of the first integers in every lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

I have these five lists in which i want to get the values of each place added up. For example, if my list is:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want the count of the first value be 2, the second 4, and so on and so on

Answer (score 4):

Put them into a 2D list, transpose it with `zip`, `map` it to `sum`, and send it to `list` to evaluate that lazy object (`list()` call not needed in Python 2, as it returns a list already).

```
>>> l = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
... [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
... [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
... [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
... [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*l)))
[2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do something like this

```
a = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
list(map(sum, zip(*a)))
```

Comment: There's no need for the inner `map`, as `sum()` can handle a tuple.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ah that's true. I'll fix that. Also, nice answer haha.